# how to display imagelist with thread on android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, imageview, imagelist

I am trying to display different image in imagelist with thread but the result is all image display in my screen with dynamic time :(

please help..how to display image one by one with specific time.

this is my code :

```
 private static String[] Imgid = {"jublagdang.png", "jublagding.png","jublagdong.png","jublagdung.png"};



 Runnable vv = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int x = 0 ;
             int y = 0;
            for(int i = 0;i<Imgid.length;i++)
            {
                 final String imagename = Imgid[i];
                         try
                         {
                             Thread.sleep(5000);
                             Assets.lirik = null;

                         }
                         catch (InterruptedException e)
                         {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         Graphics h = game.getGraphics();
                         Assets.lirik = h.newImage(imagename, ImageFormat.RGB565);

                         h.drawImage(Assets.lirik, x, y);
                         Assets.lirik = null;
                        }
        }

    };

    Thread aa = new Thread(vv);
    aa.start();
```

Comment: Use a `Handler` object instead of a thread

Answer (score 0):

Add lazy loading on your code. then you can restrict your number of images,

you can get lot of examples for lazy loading in list view from google